# What is the correlations between the Wiener processes in Heston Model?

Tags: options, stochastic-processes

In [Heston Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heston_model) we have two Wiener processes: One for the asset price, the other for the volatility. The model assumes a correlation $\rho$ between the two processes.

I ask what nature this correlation has. According to implementations I've seen online, it seems to be a simple linear correlation. Meaning, for example, if the the current (time $t$) $W^s_t$ price process has z-score of, say $+2$, and if the correlation $\rho$ is positive than it put higher likelihood of having positive z-score for the current volatility process $W^u_t$.

But why assume this kind of correlation between the processes? what does reality reveals? positive or negative for, say, index fund? Intuitively, I would expect a correlation but not linear like this - maybe taking into account absolute value of the z-score of the $W^s_t$

Comment: Leverage effect: Uncertainty rises in recessions, i.e., volatility and returns correlate negatively. This insight goes back to Black (1976).